# getting Jquery code to run inside a panel

Tags: jquery, html

The main page calls test.php when the user clicks on the Upload link . test.php has code to display the name of the file in a text box. When the code in test.php is run it displays the name of the file to upload because of the jquery in the file . But when I call the page in a panel from the main page it doesn't work. I tried to add the Jquery function to the document on load event  in both the pages but doesn't seem to make a difference.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function(){
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#loading').fadeOut( 400, "linear" );
            }, 300);
        });
        $(document).on('change', ':file', function() {
            var input = $(this),
                numFiles = input.get(0).files ? input.get(0).files.length : 1,
                label = input.val().replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '');
            input.trigger('fileselect', [numFiles, label]);
          });
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $(' li').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $this = $(this);
            $('.panel').hide();
            $('#' + $this.find('a').attr('href')).show();
            return false;
            });
            $(':file').on('fileselect', function(event, numFiles, label) {

          var input = $(this).parents('.input-group').find(':text'),
              log = numFiles > 1 ? numFiles + ' files selected' : label;

          if( input.length ) {
              input.val(log);
          } else {
              if( log ) alert(log);
          }

        });
        }); // end ready
    </script>
 <!-- #sidebar-menu -->

  <div id="page-sidebar" aria-expaned ="true">   
    <div class="scroll-sidebar">
    <ul id="sidebar-menu">
    <li class="active"><a href="panel1" title="test" ><span><font color ="black"> Upload </font></span></a></li>
    </ul><!-- #sidebar-menu -->
    </div>
    </div>
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
                <div id ="panel1" class="panel panel-primary" style="display: none;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
                    <script>$( "#panel1" ).load( 'test.php','#page-content'); </script>
                </div>             
        </div>
    </div>              
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

test.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge,chrome=1'>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<!--<script src="js/upload_script.js"></script> -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
  // We can attach the `fileselect` event to all file inputs on the page
  $(document).on('change', ':file', function() {
    var input = $(this),
        numFiles = input.get(0).files ? input.get(0).files.length : 1,
        label = input.val().replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '');
    input.trigger('fileselect', [numFiles, label]);
  });

  // We can watch for our custom `fileselect` event like this
  $(document).ready( function() {
      $(':file').on('fileselect', function(event, numFiles, label) {

          var input = $(this).parents('.input-group').find(':text'),
              log = numFiles > 1 ? numFiles + ' files selected' : label;

          if( input.length ) {
              input.val(log);
          } else {
              if( log ) alert(log);
          }

      });
  });
}); 
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page-content-wrapper">
 <div id="page-content">
            <div id="page-title">
                        <h2>Title</h2>   
            </div>

<div class="container" style="margin-top: 20px;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-12">
            <div class="input-group">
                <label class="input-group-btn">
                    <span class="btn btn-primary">
                        Browse&hellip; <input type="file" style="display: none;" multiple>
                    </span>
                </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-12">
            <input class="btn btn-info"  type="submit" value="Submit">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
            </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking because of your poor explanation, but if I've figured it out successfully, you want the form in test.php to show the name of the uploaded file too. To do that change:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

to:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Maybe you have some goal with using jQuery upload, but PHP can upload files too. You have too much code and two pages to achieve something simple.

Comment: My apologies for the poor explanation but you have understood the problem correctly .I did try to run the code after changing the jquery library but it still doesnt work .Also I have been able to upload files with html and php code however this time I need to use bootstrap. Please send me an example.